# Create x numbers of sheet based on dataframe size

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My dataframe is has like more than 4 million rows and I understand excel can only show about 1 million per sheet. But I dont want to manually create 4 sheets as I have other datas with varying millions of rows. Is there a way to code an automatic sheet creator based on the size of the original dataframe. Would love to have a coding solution and maybe a manual input on excel itself

Edit:
original file is CSV, and I want the output to appear on excel multiple sheets. Otherwise, creating multiple CSV with the same name is fine. like "name3.csv" " name4.csv" kid of csv output

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to do this for you.

**1. Exporting to multiple csv files**

```py
import math

def save_csv(df, csv_name, max_rows):
    n = math.ceil(len(df)/max_rows) # number of csv files
    for i in range(n):
        df.iloc[i*max_rows:(i+1)*max_rows,:].to_csv(csv_name+'_'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

Calling the function:

```py
csv_name = 'my_csv_file'
max_rows = 1_000_000

save_csv(df, csv_name, max_rows)
```

**2. Exporting to multiple sheets in a single xlsx file**

```py
import math

def save_xls(df, xls_path, max_rows):
    n = math.ceil(len(df)/max_rows) # number of excel sheets
    with pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for i in range(n):
            df.iloc[i*max_rows:(i+1)*max_rows,:].to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % i)
```

Calling the function:

```py
xls_path = 'my_excel_file.xlsx'
max_rows = 1_000_000

save_xls(df, xls_path, max_rows)
```

Note: There might be an additional row with the header, so you can change the function or just use 999_999 as `max_rows`.

Comment: can it work for csv file? sorry i didnt indicate. i tried use csv but i get an error

No such keys(s): 'io.excel..writer'
No engine for filetype: ''

Comment: A csv file is only a single sheet. So you can either open the csv file with something else than excel that can display more rows, or you can create multiple csv files with 1m rows each.

Comment: I have updated the answer to export to multiple csv files. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it has helped alot @Mattravel Thank you so much